# Cannot delete AWS Mobile Hub project

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-iam

I am a user in a group with an attached policy of `AdministratorAccess`. Despite this when I attempt to delete an AWS Mobile Hub project, I get the following:

`Failed to delete project.
It looks like you do not have permission for this operation.`

Then links me to the following page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/reference-mobile-hub-iam-managed-policies.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time Mobile Hub requires a service role to perform operations in your AWS account, including deleting project resources. You can create the service role at the following link:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/mobilehub/home?#/activaterole/

We are planning on removing the service role in the future so Mobile Hub will use your account permissions to perform actions in your account. Once this change takes effect you will no longer need to have the service role in your account and administrator user permission will work without issue. You can find more information about this change here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/reference-mobile-hub-project-permissions-model.html

Sincerely,
Dan G
AWS Mobile Developer Experience